# Deploying ASP.NET MVC using apache server and mysql database

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to use an apache server deploying my asp.net MVC webapp and using mysql database? Currently I'm testing my application using the integrated xsp webserver in my mono develop.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think you can host ASP.Net MVC in apache. However, you might want to port it to mono. You can use MySQL for ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: Thanks.What do you mean to port it to mono? Currently I'm developing my asp.net mvc webapp in linux using mono-develop.

Comment: You can read more about mono @ http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page Basically is a ported version of .Net so that it's cross platform etc etc

Comment: I already setup all configuration, but when I access my app, it only shows the files in the directory.

Comment: Yes. Because apache doesn't know how to translate .aspx files.

Comment: I see, but my other webapp built using asp.net webforms are ok. But the in mvc, it only shows the files.

Comment: not to sure. You need to show us the config of your apache.

Answer (score 3):

In windows you can use mod_aspdotnet, see

https://serverfault.com/questions/132846/configuring-asp-net-mvc2-on-apache-2-2-using-mod-aspdotnet

In linux you can create web application config file using online tool in go-mono.com web site and put this file to apache config directory like /etc/httpd